# Html.DropDownListFor value not selected on edit mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I am succesfullly able to save value to database (title value) on insert , but when i render the same view in edit mode then title field must hold the selected value but in my case no value is selected by title dropdown...dont know why i am getting a dropdown with nothing selected while title field holds the stored value(at backend).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, new SelectList(Model.titles, "Value", "Text"),"-Select-") // nothing selected on edit mode

 @Model.title //displaying the stored value which the user selected initially.
```

**values for title**

```
titles = new SelectList(ListItem.getValues().ToList(), "Value", "Text").ToList();
```

getValue function

```
 public static List<TextValue> getValues()
      {
    List<TextValue> titles= new List<TextValue>();
    TextValue T= new TextValue();


   T.Value = "Mr";
   T.Text = "Mr";
   titles.Add(T);

    T= new TextValue();
    T.Value = "Mrs";
    T.Text ="Mrs";
       titles.Add(T);

     T= new TextValue();
   T.Value = "Miss";
   T.Text = "Miss";
    titles.Add(T);

    T= new TextValue();
    T.Value ="Other";
   T.Text = "Other";
   titles.Add(T);


    return titles;

   }
```

Comment: probably you are saving char() to database and if so, then at edit mode you are getting spaces along with the text...check if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to use another ctor of SelectList

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)
```

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text
>   field, and a **selected value**.

Then :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, 
                      new SelectList(Model.titles, "Value", "Text", Model.title),
                      "-Select-")
```

By the way, it's generally a good idea to follow basics standards (at least) : your properties should begin by an Upper case char.

```
public string Title {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Views:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, Model.titles, "-Select-")
```

Controllers:

```
    Model.titles = new SelectList(ListItem.getValues(), "Value", "Text");

    public static List<SelectListItem> getValues()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> titles= new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem T= new SelectListItem();

        T.Value = "Mr";
        T.Text = "Mr";
        titles.Add(T);

        T = new SelectListItem();
        T.Value = "Mrs";
        T.Text = "Mrs";
        titles.Add(T);

        T = new SelectListItem();
        T.Value = "Miss";
        T.Text = "Miss";
        titles.Add(T);

        T = new SelectListItem();
        T.Value = "Other";
        T.Text = "Other";
        titles.Add(T);

        return titles;
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int sno)
    {
        var model = db.table.SingleOrDefault(x => x.sno == sno);
        return View(model);
    }
```